# Not included on a project I feel that I should have been

Tags: work-environment

My manager made it abundantly clear that his xx team was comprised of Person A and Person B. I agree that I did not have any input into the content that he presented on, but I felt affected by the fact that he named his team as Person A and Person B and left me out.

Should I speak to him about this? I am conscious about not coming across as a cry baby but I feel that I should voice my feelings.

Comment: Do you have any involvement with 'xx'?

Comment: Are you concerned that you were not included on project xx or that your name was not mentioned?

Comment: That my name was excluded when the term "team" was called out

Answer (score 5):

I realise that it can be a sting when you are excluded from something that you really wanted to be involved in. But when you try to look at the situation objectively, ask yourself these questions:

- Do you have any skills that are necessary for the completion of xx?
- What skills do Person A and Person B have that you don't, or perhaps have more of than you have?
- What other tasks are you working on, and how important or urgent are they compared to xx?

While there may be subjective reasons for your exclusion from this project, there are also likely a good number of solid, *business* reasons for it as well.  Your employer's goal here is to service their clients with the least cost.  If that means putting Person A and B on one project and you on another, then that is what they will do.

After asking yourself these questions, if you truly feel that you should have been involved in the project because you are the best person to do so, you may ask your manager if there was any other reason why you weren't included.  They may be able to give you some clarification as to if there were any business reasons that you can't see right now in your disappointment.

Comment: Jane, thanks for your detailed comment. I did not have any involvement with xx, however I have been doing a lot of other things more efficiently than Person B (in this stance) and definitely in line with the team's objectives, Person A being the manager. I have also been communicating very explicitly to Person A and assessing priorities and I feel that I have been betrayed in this instance. I feel that my manager should not have called out the name of the team. They should have spoken about the names of the members instead. Again, I don't want to be a cry baby but I want to speak out.

Comment: Unfortunately your manager is responsible for how that they allocate their team's resources.  Unless you want to go over their head to _their_ manager (and I do not recommend this unless you have very solid evidence as to there being some level of misconduct here), then there is little you can do.  If you are sure that the reason is subjective and that your manager won't change their mind, there is not much you can do to alter the project assignments.  However, if Person B is not capable there is the potential of project failure that the manager will have to explain to their bosses.